# Maven claims Cyclic references but none exist

Tags: maven, cyclic-dependency

Here is my parent module POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>io.paratek.dynalib</groupId>
<artifactId>dynalib</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>dynanode</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.paratek.dynalib</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynanode</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>dynalib</artifactId>
    <groupId>io.paratek.dynalib</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>dynanode</artifactId>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you see my child has ZERO dependencies, however, maven is spitting out

```
[ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='io.paratek.dynalib:dynalib:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='io.paratek.dynalib:dynanode:1.1-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph io.paratek.dynalib:dynanode:1.1-SNAPSHOT --> io.paratek.dynalib:dynalib:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> io.paratek.dynalib:dynanode:1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I cannot get maven to recognize 'dynanode' as a dependency in 'dynalib'. There are no errors in the pom file yet I can't use dynanode functions in dynalib.

Comment: Shouldn't the child packaging be something else than pom?

Comment: In your parent pom.xml, why are you having your module project in our dependencies?

Comment: There is a cyclic reference cause in you parent you define a dependency to a dependency which will be build in the module which defined as submodule so this is simply impossible. Apart from that a parent (packaging: pom) should never have dependencies on artifacts which are being build in the same reactor cause it will not work...

Answer (score 0):

Recreated the project and everything works, poms are the same.